# RenderTransform on a Grid (Rotate grid but not the Text inside)

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `Grid`, inside i have draw some shapes and i have also two `Textblocks`
I am trying to rotate my grid (angle=90°) but the problem is that my Text inside `TextBlocks` are being reversed with the rotation

I have tried the use of `RenderTransform` with the propreties `ScaleX` and `ScaleY`, but it has effect on all the elements

MyQuestionIs : How can I rotate the grid without affecting the text inside (just rotate shapes)

This is the Grid that i have :[image]

This is what i want to get as result :[image]

This what i'm getting after trying RenderTransform :[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Negative RotateTransform onto your `TextBlock`s. What you need to do is to write a `NegativeConverter` which implements `IValueConverter` and Bind the `RotateTransform` of `TextBlock` to the `Grid`.

[image: The <code>TextBlock</code>s that not rotating with the <code>Grid</code>]

I've written the converter:

```
public class NegativeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => value is double number ? -number : 0.0;

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Use this `NegativeConverter` in your XAML:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <local:NegativeConverter x:Key="NegativeConverter" />
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5 0.5" />
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding (UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle), ElementName=RootGrid, Converter={StaticResource NegativeConverter}}" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

The code shown below is my whole XAML file. By reading this code, you may figure out how this solution works:

```
<Window x:Class="Walterlv.Demo.Wpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Walterlv.Demo.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard.RotateAll">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                             Duration="0:0:5" From="0" To="360" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard.RotateAll}" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="8" />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform />
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:NegativeConverter x:Key="NegativeConverter" />
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5 0.5" />
                <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding (UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle), ElementName=RootGrid, Converter={StaticResource NegativeConverter}}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Fill="Gray" Width="32" Height="32" Margin="4" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Fill="Gray" Width="32" Height="32" Margin="4" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Fill="Gray" Width="32" Height="32" Margin="4" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5" Text="01:30" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5" Text="01:30" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer, i also found a simple way to do it, i used `ScaleTransform` to all the grid then i added an implicite `<style>` targeted on `TextBlock` to add another scale to get it in the right Direction.

Comment: The `Style` I added in my code is an implicit style for all `TextBlocks` in the `Grid`.